# Using spring security to reset password when password expired

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are building a web application using spring security to protect our app, but we have some problem setting up the logic when userpassword expired. the logic we attempted is

1. password reset page only accessible if user has certain role
2. update the user role in `UserDetailsService` when we found user passwd expired
3. redirect to the pass reset page if `CredentialsExpiredException` thrown.

we have configured a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
public class AuthConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login.jsp").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/my/**").hasRole("CHANGEPASS")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
          .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.jsp")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
       .failureHandler(exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler())
  }
}
```

and in *`exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler`* we configured `CredentialsExpiredException` url to my/changepass.

we also set our `UserDetailsService` that if we found out that password is expired, assigning the user a new role to "CHANGEPASS"

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    SystemUser su = userService.getUser(username);
    ...
    if (passExpired) {
        String roles = su.getRole();
        if (!roles.contains("CHANGEPASS")) {
            roles = roles + ",ROLE_CHANGEPASS";
            su.setRole(roles);
            userService.updateUser(su);
        }
    }

    return new User(username, su.getPassword(), true, true, 
}
```

Basing on the request log of the server, we saw when `CredentialsExpiredException` happens, the request is redirected to my/changepass page, **but it was then redirected to the login page**

is there any way access the change pass page when `CredentialsExpiredException` happens.

Comment: Clearly, your `.hasRole("CHANGEPASS")` isn't working. Try `.access()` instead.